# Why evaluate() in Protractor?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e

When I run the below snippet, I got the following output. But I'm still unclear why and when evaluate() has to used ....

```
    browser.get('https://weather.com/en-IN');

    $$("input[data-ng-change='goSearch()']").evaluate('placeholderText').then(function(value) {
        console.log(value);
      });
```

[image]

Comment: `evaluate()` method is used to obtain the value of any $scope variable inside the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`evaluate()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.evaluate) is rarely used, but has a unique purpose - it gives you an **access to the scope** of the current element you are working with. This is usually needed when a value you are looking for is not exposed in the HTML as an attribute or element's text.

For example, when you have a repeater over an array of objects and you need to access some object property that is not in the HTML:

```
element.all(by.repeater("address in addresses")).filter(function (elm) {
     return elm.evaluate("address.zipCode").then(function (zipCode) {
          return zipCode === "10801";
     });
});
```